# Nginx servers configuration

Tags: node.js, nginx

I’m trying to configure nginx. I have 2 node.js servers in my project. First is working. And here’s nginx configuration file for it:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.myhоst.com

    location / {
        root /home/my-project/server1/app;
        index index.html index.htm;
        proxy_pass http://server1_ip:8080/; 
    }

       location /server_2 {
        root /home/my-project/server2/app;
        index index.html index.htm;
        proxy_pass http://server2_ip:5050/; 
    }

}
```

The first server is running correctly when I’m opening www.myhоst.com/ , but the second one when I’m passing www.myhost.com/server2 link is not. How I can fix it?

Comment: Have u reloaded nginx after the making changes in the config?

Comment: yes@AkashDathan